# How to interact (connect and send queries) from an ec2 to a sql database in another ec2? using python 3 code

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, amazon-web-services

I would like to know how to interact (connect and send queries) from an ec2 to a sql database in another ec2? using python 3 code and a MySQL database (in one of the EC2).

Searchin within the previous questions I saw something about using mysql-connector so I installed mysql-connector module, but I can't get the things going, can someone please help me on this?

Please, be as detailed as possible since I know some Python3 but I'm new to AWS, maybe a sort of "roadmap" about what should I read/investigate might be helpfull and welcome as well.

Thanks in advance, regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the following code in my EC2 instance, I could pull the info stored in a database located in another EC2(RDS) instance.

```
import pymysql

host = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com"
pass_w = "PassWinfo" #<-- the password (not a key info)
user = "UserName"  #<-- user name
data_b = "Xxxxxxxx" #<-- database name
port = 3306

conn = pymysql.connect(host, port = port, user = user, password = pass_w, db = data_b)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tableName;")
result = cur.fetchall()
```

I hope this helps you.